Use Taylor expansions to find if an improper integral converges
I'm trying to decide if the following integral $$\begin{align*}
\int _{1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{1/x^{2}}-1)^{\alpha}}{\log^{\beta}\left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right)} \ dx
\end{align*}$$ is convergent or not.
For the solution, it uses Taylor expansion: When $x\to \infty$, we have $$\begin{align*}
e^{1/x^{2}} -1&=  1+ \frac{1}{x^{2}} +O\left( \frac{1}{x^{4}} \right) -1
\\ &=  \frac{1}{x^{2}} +O\left( \frac{1}{x^{4}} \right)
\end{align*}$$ and $$\begin{align*}
\log^{}\left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right) = \frac{1}{x} +O\left( \frac{1}{x^{2}} \right)
\end{align*}$$ Thus, the integrand has the following behavior: When $x\to \infty$, $$\begin{align*}
\frac{(e^{1/x^{2}}-1)^{\alpha}}{\log^{\beta}\left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right)} = \frac{\left( \frac{1}{x^{2}} +O\left( \frac{1}{x^{4}} \right) \right)^{\alpha}}{\left( \frac{1}{x} + O\left( \frac{1}{x^{2}} \right) \right)^{\beta}}
\end{align*}$$ However, the solution immediately follows that $$\begin{align*}
\frac{\left( \frac{1}{x^{2}} +O\left( \frac{1}{x^{4}} \right) \right)^{\alpha}}{\left( \frac{1}{x} + O\left( \frac{1}{x^{2}} \right) \right)^{\beta}} = \frac{1}{x^{2\alpha -\beta}} \left( 1+O\left( \frac{1}{x^{2}} \right) \right)
\end{align*}$$ I'm wondering how I could get the result above. I know that I can have $$\begin{align*}
\frac{\left( \frac{1}{x^{2}} +O\left( \frac{1}{x^{4}} \right) \right)^{\alpha}}{\left( \frac{1}{x} + O\left( \frac{1}{x^{2}} \right) \right)^{\beta}}= \frac{\frac{1}{x^{2\alpha}}\left( 1+ O\left( \frac{1}{x^{2}} \right) \right)^{\alpha}}{\frac{1}{x^{\beta}}\left( 1+O\left( \frac{1}{x^{}} \right) \right)^{\beta}} = \frac{1}{x^{2\alpha -\beta}} \frac{\left( 1+ O\left( \frac{1}{x^{2}} \right) \right)^{\alpha}}{\left( 1+O\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \right)^{\beta}}
\end{align*}$$ Then I get stuck in dealing with the term $\dfrac{\left( 1+ O\left( \frac{1}{x^{2}} \right) \right)^{\alpha}}{\left( 1+O\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \right)^{\beta}}$  .
Any help with this? Thanks!

Perhaps use $\dfrac1{1+u} = 1-u +O(u^2)$?

That looks promising. I now I think I can have $( \frac{1}{1+O( \frac{1}{x} )} )^{\beta}= ( 1+O( \frac{1}{x} ) )^{\beta}$
Thus we have $\dfrac{( 1+ O( \frac{1}{x^{2}} ) )^{\alpha}}{( 1+O( \frac{1}{x} ) )^{\beta}}=( 1+O( \frac{1}{x^{2}} ) )^{\alpha}( 1+O( \frac{1}{x} ) )^{\beta}$ . Then I tried to use $(1+x)^{\alpha}=1+\alpha x +O(x^{2}),x\to 0$ . Thus we have $[ 1+\alpha O( \frac{1}{x^{2}} ) ][ 1+\beta O( \frac{1}{x}) ]$ . However, there still $O( \frac{1}{x})$ is left. Since $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x}=\infty$, so I can't tell if the integral is convergent. Can you give me more ideas?

Yes, you're right.  So the integral will be convergent iff $2\alpha-\beta>1$. I don't see the relevance of the $O(1/x)$ versus $O(1/x^2)$ terms. The leading term dominates, no?

Now I see. Thank you very much!

Given the form of the integral, it makes sense to change variables from $x$ to ${1 \over x}$, so that you need to analyze the convergence of
$$\int_0^1 \frac{(e^{x^2} - 1)^{\alpha}}{x^2\log^{\beta}(1 + x)}\,dx$$
The only issue is the singularity at $x = 0$ since the integrand is continuous elsewhere. Now use that $e^{x^2} - 1 = x^2 + o(x^2)$ and $\log(1 + x) = x + o(x)$ to realize that the integrand is of the form $x^{2\alpha - \beta - 2} + o(x^{2\alpha - \beta - 2})$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. Thus the integral will converge when $2\alpha - \beta - 2 > -1$ or $2\alpha - \beta > 1$.

The integrand can be represented as
$$\left ({e^{1/x^2}-1\over {1\over x^2}}\right )^\alpha\left ( {{1\over x }\over \log (1+1/x)}\right )^\beta {1\over x^{2\alpha-\beta}}$$ The limit at $\infty$  of the first two factors is equal $1.$ Thus convergence occurs iff $2\alpha -\beta >1.$
Remark For the first two factors we can apply $$\lim_{x\to \infty}{e^{1/x^2}-1\over {1\over x^2}}=\lim_{t\to 0}{e^t-1\over t}=(e^t)'\big\lvert_{t=0}=1$$ $$\lim_{x\to \infty}{{1\over x}\over \log(1+1/x)}\ \underset{t=\log(1+1/x)}{=}\ \lim_{t\to 0}{e^t-1\over t}=1$$
Hence just one property is used $e^t=1+t+o(t), \ t\to 0.$
